# Using a model trained by SvmPerf or LibLinear

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am writing a machine learning program in Node.js, and I want to use libraries such as LibLinear and SvmPerf, that are not available in Node.js. So, for training, I just create a file with the training samples, and execute the SvmPerf binary on that file. I can also do the same for classification, but, since classification occurs much more than training, this may be too slow.

So I thought of a different approach: since the classification in SVM (with linear kernel) is just an inner product of the model weights with the feature values of the input, I can just read the SvmPerf model file, parse it and keep the weights in memory, and then do the classification myself in Node.js.

Is this approach correct? Can I indeed do the classifiction by calculating the inner product between the model created by SvmPerf/LibLinear and the input sample?

Comment: If you are still interessed to use libsvm on node, there is library  called [node-svm](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/node-svm) (based on libsvm 3.17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**. In the binary, linear case all you have to do is retrieve the coordinates of the `w` hyperplane and the `b` parameter, compute `<w,x>-b` for the new point `x` and return the sign of the result. In case of multi label classification you willl have to implement some kind of voting scheme according to used library method (1 vs all or 1 vs 1).

Most of the libraries do not store the `w` parameter, instead they store the list of support vectors `sv_i` with corresponding "weights" `slpha_i y_i` (often as a one number per vector). To retrieve the `w` parameter you have to calculate the `w = sum_i alpha_i y_i sv_i`. And the `b` variable is sometimes called `intercept`

Comment: This answer should be combined with carlosdc's answer, which adds important information about LibLinear.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add a couple of things to lejlot's excellent answer:

- What lejlot says is exactly right if you're using LIBSVM or any other SVM library with a linear kernel: you will need to convert the SVM model (support vectors and lagrangian multipliers) to a w.
- In the case the OP is interested, he is using LIBLINEAR (not an SVM library). LIBLINEAR automatically generates the w. He would only need to extract it from the model and add it to his Javascript program
- The part about the b is only required if you used -b 1 in training the classifier in LIBLINEAR. He would obtain one extra dimension in the w, and he would need to append a 1 to his data prior to classification.

Comment: Thanks! Another issue with the LibLinear format, which I just found out, is that, in case of a binary classification, the model contains only a single weight vector, and it might be either of the positive (1) class or the negative (0) class, depending on the value in the "labels" field.

Comment: Additionally, when doing multiclass classification in LibLinear (With more than 2 classes), the model contains a vector for each class; each vector is a column.